# Why does $\sum_{n=2}^ \infty \frac 1 {n \sqrt {\log n}}$ diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I'm aware that this diverges, but I'm struggling to prove it only using a comparison, or a ratio/root test.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated - this isn't even an assignment question, just one that I can't seem to get out of my head.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The integral test works here.

Comment: There's a reason that those tests(root/ratio) are only sufficient conditions and not necessary ones. That means if the ratio test gives limit $1$ , then they are inconclusive. So , no , in particualr you **cannot** prove it only using a root/ratio test. Comparison on the other hand works only when you know for sure if the series you are comparing it to converges or diverges. So that won't bear any fruit either since the series' which you'll end up comparing it too, would require proof of whether they converge or not. In general when you see logs, Cauchy Condensation test is the way to go.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron My understanding is that ratio test is incapable of showing _very slow_ divergence. And comparison test is good to get rid of chaotic behaviour - say if I multiplied the terms by 5 + sin n. This function converges very slowly and is perfectly regular, so these don’t help.

Answer (score 0):

A good observation here is the series diverges if the following indefinite integral diverges:
$$
\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x \sqrt{\ln x}} dx 
$$
Notice how I used $\ln x$ instead of $\log x$? The base change does not affect the evaluation in this particular situation, it just makes it easier to compute the integral. We are going to use substitution: Let $u = \ln x$ then $du = \frac1x dx \Leftrightarrow  x du= dx$. We have the following:
$$
\int_{\ln (2)}^\infty \frac{du}{\sqrt{u}} = (2\sqrt u) |^\infty_{\ln 2} = \infty 
$$

The integral diverges, so the series diverges.

Comment: errgg45654 wrote "*prove it only using a comparison, or a ratio/root test*"

Answer (score -3):

The sum of 1/n diverges, but just very slowly. Check out *why* it diverges and why it diverges so slowly.

You added a factor that makes it grow slower. Depending on that factor, it might sill be divergent, but even slower. It might be enough to limit the series. Or it might make a proof difficult. In this case it’s still divergent.

For the sum from 1 to 2, from 3 to 4, from 5 to 8, from 9 to 16, from 17 to 32 and so on find a simple upper and lower limit. So the sum is between xxx and yyy. And then you sum this up. For the sum of 1/n, the sum up to 2^k is at least some constant times k. Do the same here.